# How to include rpm dependency in setup.py

Tags: dependencies, rpm, setuptools, python-2.6

I'm new to python but i want to create rpm package by using setuptools and bdist_rpm option.
The problem I've occurred is how to include dependencies to other rpm (c/c++ binaries libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the dependencies to the Requires section, see [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-rpm-packages).

Comment: The problem is i saw that requires option in setup.py which should generate Requires in rpm spec file, but it doesnt :). And that's the problem. I will keep on trying ;)

Comment: You should either pass it via command-line, or by using a `setup.cfg` file, see http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/configfile.html#setup-config .

Comment: thx guyz, later i found there is something like setup.cfg(thx smani) which looks very similar to setup.py, kinda fooled me.

Comment: Does this also work for using bdist_wheel when creating a wheel that depends on python that is installed via rpm?